# Scrapy-Playwrite program only load periphery page elements

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, extract, screen-scraping, scrapy-playwright

A program that I wrote using scrapy and scrapy-playwright only seems to load the periphery elements of the page. The "meat of the page" remains blank, but unfortunately that is the information I'm trying to scrape from

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/ext/22-accessibility
```

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod

import asyncio



class ExtensionSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "extension"
    allowed_domains = ["chrome.google.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/ext/22-accessibility',
            meta={
                'playwright': True,
                'playwright_include_page': True,
                'playwright_page_method': [
                    PageMethod('wait_for_selector', '//h1'),
                    PageMethod('evaluate', 'window.scrollBy(0, document.body.scrollHeight)'),
                    PageMethod('wait_for_timeout', 30000),
                ],
                'errback': self.errback,
            },
            headers={
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
            },
            callback=self.parse,
        )

    async def parse(self, response):
        page = response.meta["playwright_page"]
        h1_element = response.xpath('//h1/text()').get()
        grids = response.xpath('//div[@role="grid"]').getall()
        screenshot = await page.screenshot(path="example.png", full_page=True)

        await page.close()

        yield {
            'H1 Loaded': h1_element,
            'Number of grids': len(grids)
        }

    async def errback(self, failure):
        page = failure.request.meta["playwright_page"]
        await page.close()
```

I'm having a strange problem with my code, basically only the periphery elements of the page load (see image attached), i want to access the 'meat of the page' but no matter if i type wait_for_selector or wait_for_timeout i only get the sidebar and header of the page

[image]

as you can see from the screenshot of my page, only the header and sidebar loads